# SSL for PostgreSQL connection nodejs and express to conection on render host service

Tags: node.js, express, openssl, render

The solution ist next:
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const db = new Pool({
user:'user',
host: 'host',
database: 'database',
password: 'pass',
port: 5432,
//solution to render ssl
ssl: true
});

module.exports = db;

The solution ist next:
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const db = new Pool({
user:'user',
host: 'host',
database: 'database',
password: 'pass',
port: 5432,
//solution to render ssl
ssl: true
});

module.exports = db;
//solution

Comment: Hi, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you!